# A possible Corollary of the Fredholm alternative?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $P : H \rightarrow H$ a positive-definite (bounded) operator and $K : H \rightarrow H$ a compact (not necessarily self-adjoint) operator.

Let $T = P + K$. In particular, $T$ is Fredholm of index zero.

For each **negative** real number $c$, let $S_c$ denote the set of solutions $x$ of the equation

$$T(x) = cx.$$

How can I show that $S = \cup_{c < 0} S_c$ is finite?

I know about the Fredholm alternative, but I don't know how to apply it to this situation, since I need the operator $T$ to be of the form $\lambda\mathrm{Id} + K$, and the usual tricks (changing basis, composing with inverses, etc.) don't seem to quite work. If there is such a trick, I'd appreciate a more detailed explanation of why it works. Thanks!

Comment: Let $\{ e_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal subset of $H$. Define $Px = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ on the closed span of the $e_{n}$, and define $P=I$ on the orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by the $e_{n}$. Let $K=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(x,e_{n})e_{n}$. Then $K$ is compact and $P+K$ has infinitely many negative eigenvalues. Notice that $(Px,x) > 0$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @T.A.E. You're right, the statement is false. Thanks for the counterexample. If you don't mind me asking, could the statement be true if we assumed $P$ to be an isomorphism?

Comment: Hi, let's assume that $P$ is positive definite. I think it must be true in that case, but I'm not certain. Nobody has answered; so is it okay if I change your question to "positive definite" from "positive"?

Comment: @T.A.E. yes, by all means.